# Delete ruby user records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a ruby app and want to delete my testing users in the SQL database is there a command line to delete them all. Like to start fresh through testing

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rails db:migrate:reset`to delete everything and recreate your database

Comment: Ok this will simply delete the contents of the fields ie users names , emails however will not delete the db fields entirely?

Comment: It will drop all tables and then recreate them so they will all be empty.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only want to delete users and not other models, you can open rails console and run User.delete_all

Answer (score 0):

To delete database in rails using command lines run in this command in the rails app directory.

```
bundle exec rake db:drop:all
```

The  above code will delete the entire database. Alternatively you can delete the database using mysql also by listing all the databases present and choosing the one to delete.

Open up terminal and type `mysql -u yourusername -p`, hit enter and type your root password.

```
show databases; 
drop database yourdatabase;
```